How to make the Event Stream (EventSource()) working with cloudflare?
basically i am using an ai tool api, so i create a POST request first to create a database entry then to get a streaming output I do it using EventSource()
this works perfectly in deployment even (without cloudflare)
i have tried these all changes

I enabled dev mode in cloudflare
I added these cache rules too with full bypassing cache
first rule

(any(http.request.headers["accept"][*] eq "text/event-stream")) or (any(http.request.headers[":accept:"][*] eq "text/event-stream"))

second rule
(http.request.uri contains "/api/tools/video-generate?user=") or (http.request.uri contains "/api/tools/image-generate?user=") or (http.request.uri contains "/api/tools/music-generate?user=")


I also added this in API backend as headers

res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    "Content-Encoding": "none",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-transform",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    "X-Accel-Buffering": "no",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": allowedOrigins.includes(origin)
        ? origin
        : "null",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
});


I also added this in my nginx config
proxy_set_header X-Accel-Buffering no;

now in deployment when the code is running, I get this error
ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR  - i got this error once
but some user get this error
ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR - but now everytime I get this error only
so definitely something is wrong, and I think other users get other error messages not sure
I even added page rules

but still error comes ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR
also once I did the 4th point then in the api call, i was able to see EventStream, but as soon as a new write request is done, the error comes. the first write request does get received but not the rest.
